# How to generate mongodb object id for a sub-document on insert

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Inserting a document that also has sub-documents. I am doing this through cli. How do I make mongodb generate a object id for the Alerts sub-document record? I want something like the following, but this does not work from cli.

```
db.user.insert(
{
    "Email" : "andy+5@domain.com",
    "Domain" : "other",
    "Type" : "local",
    "FName" : "Andy",
    "Alerts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : new ObjectId(),
            "Keyword" : "sales",
            "Frequency" : {
                "Type" : "daily"
            },
            "IsActive" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : new ObjectId(),
            "Keyword" : "customer service",
            "Frequency" : {
                "Type" : "daily"
            },
            "IsActive" : true
        } 
    ]
}
)
```

Comment: It should be working. I can cut and paste that and get the ObjectId's where you defined them.

Comment: What is inserted when you try that? `db.user.find({ Email: "andy+5@domain.com" })`

Comment: Actually was running this in a robomongo insert form and not cli. My mistake. It does indeed work from cli.

Comment: I see that it works as a command from the cli. But is there a way to make this work from the Insert/Edit Document form? Obviously without the db.user.insert() around it. I keep getting "Unable to parse JSON".

Comment: This seems to be a big issue with Robomongo's JSON parser.

Answer (score 8):

You can run that exact script on the console on robomongo, it would execute just fine. Don't do it on add or edit dialog.